# Netbeans GUI editor problems

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, netbeans

Im making a portion of my app using the netbeans gui editor.

Great so far. However ive added a new checkbox - and when i load the panel in my app the text attribute isnt shown...its just blank as if i have no caption on it... all the other ones display - so this is very annoying. It kind of seems that I have hit the limit on gui items or something, becasue any new items I add I cannot seem then, If i add new labels they dont show either :S!

The other problems Im having are that the size of the window im editting appears to be fixed - every time i change it, it jumps back to the same size - how do i stop this from happening?

Cheers

Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a "Clean and Build" on your project and run it again.  I've had the same problem.  The GUI builder in NetBeans stores the text for your components in a properties file.  New properties don't seem to be loaded properly when you just run the project in the IDE until you do a fresh build.

Comment: Nice one cheers - thats fixed it! That had me completely confused!

Any ideas about how to get the screen to size correctly?!

Comment: @RenegadeAndy: That one I haven't seen before.  Is it changing size when you run the app, or right in the editor window?  Could you post a screen-shot in your question?

Answer (score 0):

See http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=136425 for a related bug report.